# i want to validate date in javascript.can anyone help me in understandin this?

Tags: javascript

```
var dcheck=/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-\{4}$/;/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-\{4}$/;
```

can anyone one help me in understanding this part

```
"/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-\{4}$/;/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-\{4}$/"
```

....can u please tell me how this checks the input also?

```
if(dcheck.test(dor)){
        document.getElementById('div_id').innerHTML="Correct Entry";    
    }
else{
   document.getElementById('div_id').innerHTML="please check ";
  }
```

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: you can use this page to test your expression http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: If you enter the regular expression at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and hover over each piece of it, you'll get a tooltip that says what it does.

Comment: http://regex101.com/ will also provide explanation on what each part of your regex means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-{4}$/` is a regular expression, commonly used to match strings of various forms. Let's step through it bit by bit to figure out what it's doing.

`/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-`:

Here, we check if the string starts with a certain two-digit string. The vertical bar here means or, so either we match `0?[1-9]`, `[12][0-9]`, or `3[01]`. The first means "It's a single digit day, and we don't care if you start with 0 or not." The "we don't care" is encoded by a question mark. The second is for a two-digit day where the second digit is unrestricted, and the third is saying that the date, if starting with 3, must be either 30 or 31. Finally, the - just means we end in a -, for this section.

`(0?[1-9]|1[012])-`:

Here, we do something similar. This part is of the form `0?[1-9]` or `1[012]`. Hopefully you can see, by referring to the previous paragraph, that this accepts months from 1 to 12, where single digits may start with a 0.

`{4}`

This is a new symbol we haven't seen. `{n}` just means "Accept an n-digit string".

So what we end up with is "Day-Month-Year", where the parentheses capture the day, month, and year, and stick them into variables.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Html Code:

```
<form name="frmSample" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return ValidateForm()">
            <p>Enter a Date <font color="#CC0000"><b>(mm/dd/yyyy)</b></font> 
              : 
              <input type="text" name="txtDate" maxlength="10" size="15">
            </p>
            <p> 
              <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
            </p>
          </form>
```

javascript Code:

```
<script language = "Javascript">
/**
* DHTML date validation script. Courtesy of SmartWebby.com     (http://www.smartwebby.com/dhtml/datevalidation.asp)
 */
 // Declaring valid date character, minimum year and maximum year
 var dtCh= "/";
 var minYear=1900;
 var maxYear=2100;

 function isInteger(s){
var i;
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
    // Check that current character is number.
    var c = s.charAt(i);
    if (((c < "0") || (c > "9"))) return false;
}
// All characters are numbers.
return true;
}

function stripCharsInBag(s, bag){
var i;
var returnString = "";
// Search through string's characters one by one.
// If character is not in bag, append to returnString.
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
    var c = s.charAt(i);
    if (bag.indexOf(c) == -1) returnString += c;
}
return returnString;
}

 function daysInFebruary (year){
// February has 29 days in any year evenly divisible by four,
// EXCEPT for centurial years which are not also divisible by 400.
return (((year % 4 == 0) && ( (!(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))) ? 29 : 28 );
 }
 function DaysArray(n) {
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    this[i] = 31
    if (i==4 || i==6 || i==9 || i==11) {this[i] = 30}
    if (i==2) {this[i] = 29}
 } 
  return this
 }

  function isDate(dtStr){
var daysInMonth = DaysArray(12)
var pos1=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh)
var pos2=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos1+1)
var strMonth=dtStr.substring(0,pos1)
var strDay=dtStr.substring(pos1+1,pos2)
var strYear=dtStr.substring(pos2+1)
strYr=strYear
if (strDay.charAt(0)=="0" && strDay.length>1) strDay=strDay.substring(1)
if (strMonth.charAt(0)=="0" && strMonth.length>1) strMonth=strMonth.substring(1)
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (strYr.charAt(0)=="0" && strYr.length>1) strYr=strYr.substring(1)
}
month=parseInt(strMonth)
day=parseInt(strDay)
year=parseInt(strYr)
if (pos1==-1 || pos2==-1){
    alert("The date format should be : mm/dd/yyyy")
    return false
}
if (strMonth.length<1 || month<1 || month>12){
    alert("Please enter a valid month")
    return false
}
if (strDay.length<1 || day<1 || day>31 || (month==2 && day>daysInFebruary(year)) || day > daysInMonth[month]){
    alert("Please enter a valid day")
    return false
}
if (strYear.length != 4 || year==0 || year<minYear || year>maxYear){
    alert("Please enter a valid 4 digit year between "+minYear+" and "+maxYear)
    return false
}
if (dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos2+1)!=-1 || isInteger(stripCharsInBag(dtStr, dtCh))==false){
    alert("Please enter a valid date")
    return false
}
    return true
  }

   function ValidateForm(){
var dt=document.frmSample.txtDate
if (isDate(dt.value)==false){
    dt.focus()
    return false
}
    return true
   }

    </script>
```

try this one. it may helpful to you.